# Use PowerShell to find and replace hex values in binary files

Tags: powershell, hex, edit

UPDATE:
I got a working script to accomplish the task. I needed to batch process a bunch of files so it accepts a csv file formatted as FileName,OriginalHEX,CorrectedHEX.  It's very slow even after limiting the search to the first 512 bytes.  It could probably be written better and made faster.  Thanks for the help.

UPDATE 2: Revised the search method to be faster but it's nowhere near as fast as a dedicated hex editor. Be aware that it's memory intensive. peaks around 32X the size of the file in RAM.  10MB=320MB of RAM.  100MB=3.2GB of RAM.  I don't recommend for big files.  It also saves to a new file instead of overwriting.  Original file renamed as File.ext_original@date-time.

```
Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\HEXCorrection.csv | ForEach-Object {
  $File = $_.'FileName'
  $Find = $_.'OriginalHEX'
  $Replace = $_.'CorrectedHEX'


  IF (([System.IO.File]::Exists("$PSScriptRoot\$File"))) {
    $Target = (Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\$File)
  } ELSE {
    Write-Host $File "- File Not Found`n" -ForegroundColor 'Red'
    RETURN
  }

  Write-Host "File:   "$Target.Name`n"Find:    "$Find`n"Replace: "$Replace
  $TargetLWT = $Target.LastWriteTime
  $TargetCT = $Target.CreationTime
  IF ($Target.IsReadOnly) {
    Write-Host $Target.Name "- Is Read-Only`n" -ForegroundColor 'Red'
    RETURN
  }
  $FindLen = $Find.Length
  $ReplaceLen = $Replace.Length
  $TargetLen = (1..$Target.Length)

  IF (!($FindLen %2 -eq 0) -OR !($ReplaceLen %2 -eq 0) -OR 
  [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($FindLen) -OR [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($ReplaceLen)) {
    Write-Host "Input hex values are not even or empty" -ForegroundColor 'DarkRed'
    RETURN
  } ELSEIF (
    $FindLen -ne $ReplaceLen) {
    Write-Host "Input hex values are different lengths" -ForegroundColor 'DarkYellow'
    RETURN
  }

  $FindAsBytes = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  $Find -split '(.{2})' | ? {$_} | % { $FindAsBytes += [Convert]::ToInt64($_,16) }
  $ReplaceAsBytes = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  $Replace -split '(.{2})' | ? {$_} | % { $ReplaceAsBytes += [Convert]::ToInt64($_,16) }
  # ^-- convert to base 10

  Write-Host "Starting Search"
  $FileBytes = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Target)
  FOREACH ($Byte in $FileBytes) {
        $ByteCounter++
        IF ($Byte -eq [INT64]$FindAsBytes[0]) { TRY {
             (1..([INT64]$FindAsBytes.Count-1)) | % {
               $Test = ($FileBytes[[INT64]$ByteCounter-1+[INT64]$_] -eq $FindAsBytes[$_])
               IF ($Test -ne 'True') {
                 THROW
               }
  }
    Write-Host "Found at Byte:" $ByteCounter -ForegroundColor 'Green'
    (0..($ReplaceAsBytes.Count-1)) | % {
      $FileBytes[[INT64]$ByteCounter+[INT64]$_-1] = $ReplaceAsBytes[$_]}
  $Found = 'True'
  $BytesReplaces = $BytesReplaces + [INT64]$ReplaceAsBytes.Count
  }
CATCH {}
}

}
  IF ($Found -eq 'True'){
    [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$Target-temp", $FileBytes)
    $OriginalName = $Target.Name+'_Original'+'@'+(Get-Date).ToString('yyMMdd-HHmmss')
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $Target.FullName -NewName $OriginalName
    Rename-Item $Target"-temp" -NewName $Target.Name
    #Preserve Last Modified Time
    $Target.LastWriteTime = $TargetLWT
    $Target.CreationTime = $TargetCT
    Write-Host $BytesReplaces "Bytes Replaced" -ForegroundColor 'Green'
    Write-Host "Original saved as:" $OriginalName
  } ELSE {
      Write-Host "No Matches" -ForegroundColor 'Red'}
    Write-Host "Finished Search`n"
    Remove-Variable -Name * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} # end foreach from line 1

PAUSE
```

Original: This has been asked before but found no solutions to perform a simple and straight up find hex value and replace hex value on large files, 100MB+.
Even better would be any recommendations for a hex editor with command line support for this task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete some sequence of bytes in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295131/delete-some-sequence-of-bytes-in-powershell) or [Methods to hex edit binary files via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935356/methods-to-hex-edit-binary-files-via-powershell)

Comment: @Fr3nZy, if you do not agree that this is a duplicate, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There's options over here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935356/methods-to-hex-edit-binary-files-via-powershell  But you have to be careful how many times the search and replace happens.

Comment: @js2010 Thanks. This helped me work out the 'replace' part of the script.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a first crack at it:

```
(get-content -encoding byte file) -replace '\b10\b',11 -as 'byte[]'
```

I was checking those other links, but the only answer that does search and replace has some bugs.  I voted to reopen.  The mklement0 one is close.  None of them search and then print the position of the replacement.

Nevermind.  Yours is faster and uses less memory.

Comment: That's clever. You can speed it up dramatically by adding the `-Raw` switch, which reads the entire file at once and directly returns a `byte[]` array, rather than processing the bytes one by one and collecting the result in a regular `[object[]]` array. Also, use `-as [byte[]]` instead of `-as 'byte[]'`.

Comment: Good start but how would I search and replace multiple consecutive bytes in an array?

Comment: @Fr3nZy: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57342311/45375

Comment: `+1` for the idea. If you take this one step further and convert the input byte array to a single string, I guess you can just simplify this to: `"$bInput" -Replace "\b$bOriginal\b", "$bSubstitute"  -Split '\s+' -as [Byte[]]`, see the [example in the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57353901/1701026)

Comment: Sorry about the quotes. My original csv file name and header names had spaces in them.  Thanks for beautifying it.  I'm new to PS.  Need to work on my indenting.

Comment: Revised the scripted and fixed the issue of it skipping the first byte.

Comment: Maybe you should post it over here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935356/methods-to-hex-edit-binary-files-via-powershell